# Failed beta sites are showing up in the /sites method.

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, sites

[3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics) and [Game of Go](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go) are both failed beta sites. I would not expect them to show up in the `/sites` list - but they do. Indeed, attempting to list questions on one of the sites fails:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions?site=go
>
> ```
> {
>   error_id: 400,
>   error_name: "bad_parameter",
>   error_message: "No site found for name `go`"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

Dead sites live in the infrastructure for a bit after being killed, the API just wasn't excluding them in some silly cases.